# Does app store or Play Store allow apps that have a WebView only to my site?

Tags: google-play, app-store, phonegap-desktop-app

I want to publish an app witch contains a WebView to my site only
and thats the whole app. Like Mobile Web app but comes from the stores.
Does app store or Play Store allow apps that have a WebView only to my site?

Comment: Is this question on-topic for SO? Seems like it should be closed.

Comment: i found this link to be interesting. anyone can shed some lights? it described apple's attitude towards html pages
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#third-party-software

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can published an app which contains just a WebView of your own website. Please note that according to [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), it's not allowed to publish apps that provide a WebView of a website you don't own or administer:

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>
> Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)

Reference: http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

According to [Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality),
apps which are just web views are not allowed:

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality

Comment: Hi 10x first of all. What about  apple appstore?

Comment: According to the App Store Review Guidelines, Apple will reject simple WebView apps without any additional functionality.

Comment: For apple store, if you add any native functionality like push notification, location ..., most likely they will accept it. At least they did for us.

Comment: I submitted to review an application with web-view and push notification function, but Apple still does not approve it...

Comment: Is this still true and if so, then how does Trusted Web Activities (TWA) fit in?

Comment: I've updated this answer to the latest App Store guidelines as of July 2020.

Comment: For the Play Store, I can't find the quoted section anymore; the closest is [Minimum Functionality](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9898783) which basically only states that your app must work and do _something_ :')

Comment: How to prove that I'm the owner?

Comment: @AnhTN : Is it approved

Answer (score 4):

Yes You can but when you implement webview in your application few things must keep in mind
**Webviews and Affiliate Spam**
We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to drive affiliate traffic to a website or provide a webview of a website without permission from the website owner or administrator.

**[Here are some examples of common violations:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOZPL.png)**

An app whose primary purpose is to drive referral traffic to a website to receive credit for user sign-ups or purchases on that website.
Apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website without permission:
 [Google play Developer Policy Center link](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/#!?zippy_activeEl=webviews-affiliate#webviews-affiliate)

Comment: Can i Publish a App with webview of an e-commerce website: https://bhartimart.in ?

Comment: how to prove that I'm the owner?

Comment: how do app store make sure developers don't suddenly switch their contents to some inappropriate information it everything solely comes from webview?