# My simple webview application is suspended on googleplayconsole now how can i publish again or remove it.?

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

before yesterday i uploaded my application and yesterday i get this response

> An email with details about the removal has been sent to the account owner at myEmail@gmail.com. Before uploading any new applications, please review the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies. If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit this Google Play Help Center article to learn how you can appeal against the removal.

and solve this errors and now again upload application and now i get this error.

> You need to use a different package name because "com.app.my_appliaction_name" is already used by one of your other applications.

Comment: Your previous application with package `com.app.my_appliaction_name` is suspended. So you can not use that same package again for your new app. You need to choose new package and uplod the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this community is about programming questions not legal/licensing issues of some 3rd party service.

Comment: Actually i don't think this question not relevant of programming topic may be directly webview using not allowed on play store.

Comment: and webview belong to programming yet.

Comment: this is not a programming question, if webview works as you intended to work. Also, the question is not about webview, but about handling of suspended applications by Google Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is that you need to add a **Privacy Policy** to your app and to your Console.

To do this you need to:

1. create Privacy Policy

Easy way to do this is with the [Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)

2. Add it to your app and Console

   Google Console -> your app -> store presence -> store listing -> Privacy Policy.
3. Then you need to generate .apk file (Android Studio -> Build > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK) with a **higher Version code** then before.
4. Add another release to your app – don’t create another app with the same package name.

Console -> your app -> Release management -> App releases

5. Wait

Usually it takes a few hours for google to unlock the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that according to Google Play Developer Program Policies, it's not allowed to publish apps that provide a WebView of a website you don't own or administer. Please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194912/5701085) to get references.

And about App relaunching issue, Obviously you need to change the package name to publish new App. As there is already an App present in the Google System with that package name.