# One admin page for both a website and a mobile app

Tags: php, flutter, admin

I am actually creating a mobile app using flutter for a project based on a website.
The website is built with PHP/html/css/js and actually have an admin page.
I want to know if it is possible to use that admin page for my mobile app, and if yes, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WebView. An app that in fact just showed a web page, like an iframe. There are some caveats in this approach. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170598/does-app-store-or-play-store-allow-apps-that-have-a-webview-only-to-my-site) brings a good discussion about that.

Answer (score -1):

No, I guess. Flutter codes have to be written in dart language.