# Is google Play store accept web view android app?

Tags: android, web, webview

Is google Play store accept web view android app ?

Im Web developer and i want to develop mobile app
by create android app and connect with my URL as web view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does app store or Play Store allow apps that have a WebView only to my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170598/does-app-store-or-play-store-allow-apps-that-have-a-webview-only-to-my-site)

Comment: Short answer YES, as long as you own this website also your app should contain more features, don't put just a web view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app should have some native code functionality